# 502 Bad Gateway / failing on passwordsigninasync call

Tags: c#, windows, server, asp.net-core-2.2

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult loSignInResult = await base._oLoginManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loUser.UserName, lsPassword, true, false);
```

This is the line that causes the 502 Bad Gateway message.

Please see the startup program below (_bStaging is false when this error occurs), I have tried to reorder the code without success. This error started occurring the other day without a significant code change. No changes were made to the server, and only I have access.:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection loServices)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this._bIsStaging)
            {
                loServices.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
                });
            }
            loServices.AddSession();
            Heron.Data.Classes.ConnectionStrings._sHeronConnectionString = this._oConfiguration.GetConnectionString(this.GetConnectionStringName("Heron"));
            Heron.Data.Classes.ConnectionStrings._sIdentityConnectionString = this._oConfiguration.GetConnectionString(this.GetConnectionStringName("Identity"));
            loServices.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            loServices.AddDbContext<Heron.Data.DB.HeronContext>(O => O.UseSqlServer(Heron.Data.Classes.ConnectionStrings._sHeronConnectionString));
            loServices.AddScoped<DbContext>(sp => sp.GetService<Heron.Data.DB.HeronContext>());
            loServices.AddDbContext<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.DbContext>(O => O.UseSqlServer(Heron.Data.Classes.ConnectionStrings._sIdentityConnectionString));
            loServices.AddScoped<DbContext>(sp => sp.GetService<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.DbContext>());
            loServices.AddIdentity<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.User, Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.Role>(opts =>
            {
                opts.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Heron.Library.Classes.Constants._nDefaultLockoutTime, 0);
                opts.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Heron.Library.Classes.Constants._nMaxFailedAccessAttempts;
                opts.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = Heron.Library.Classes.Constants._nMinRequiredDigitsPassword;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.DbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddUserManager<UserManager<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.User>>();
            loServices.AddScoped<SignInManager<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.User>>();
            loServices.AddScoped<UserManager<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.User>>();
            loServices.AddScoped<RoleManager<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.Role>>();
            loServices.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Index");
                options.Cookie.Name = "HeronAuthCookie";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
            loServices.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Index";
            });
            loServices.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            loServices.AddMvcCore(options =>
            {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            })
            .AddJsonFormatters();
            loServices
                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
            loServices.AddKendo();
            loServices.Configure<RecaptchaSettings>(this._oConfiguration.GetSection("RecaptchaSettings"));
            loServices.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaService>();
            loServices.Configure<IISOptions>(this._oConfiguration);
            loServices.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-GB");
                options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
            });
        }
        catch (Exception loException)
        {
            Heron.Library.Classes.Utility.MakeExceptionMessage(loException, "\r\n", "Startup.ConfigureServices");
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder loApp, IHostingEnvironment loEnv)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this._bIsStaging)
            {
                loApp.UseHttpsRedirection();
            }
            using (var serviceScope = loApp.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var loContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Heron.Data.DB.HeronContext>();
                loContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                loContext.Database.Migrate();
                var loContext2 = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Heron.Data.DB.Extensions.IdentityExtend.DbContext>();
                loContext2.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            if (loEnv.IsDevelopment())
            {
                loApp.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                loApp.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
                loApp.UseHsts();
            }
            loApp.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Status code page, status code: " + context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
            });
            loApp.UseStaticFiles();
            loApp.UseSession();
            loApp.UseCookiePolicy();
            loApp.UseAuthentication();
            loApp.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "dashboard", template: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{lsData?}");
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{lsMessage?}");
            });
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
            loApp.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });
        }
        catch (Exception loException)
        {
            Heron.Library.Classes.Utility.MakeExceptionMessage(loException, "\r\n", "Startup.Configure");
        }
    }
```

[image: Bad Gateway message after above line executes...]

Comment: We are using core 2.2 225 ASP.NET / VS 2017 / Windows Server 2016

Comment: After this error started I did modify the server by adding the latest core runtime.

Comment: Furthermore this does not happen on development machine running through the IDE...

Comment: The server is not running out of memory / it is at 50% consumption.

Comment: Note: As soon as it hits the signin line the program drops out. It does not complete the logging task in the try catch so am at a bit of a loss as to what is occurring...

Comment: FYI...Part of the website runs, the bit before the reCapture. You can see that part @ https://heron.dar-jader.com / You shall not see the error because you do not have any login credentials to get to the part of the program that illustrates the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this has been found...

https://forums.asp.net/p/2156143/6266248.aspx?p=True&t=636961808361687440

See above thread.

In essence it was a user claim value containing an image which exceeded the response header size.

This might be a problem for core as a nice place to store an image (avatar) for an identity user is within userclaim.

All for now.

David

Edit ...

The code below should point you to the User Claim area in your code.
I had to remove a User Claim containing an image (Profile Pic) which was too large for the area I was storing it in. So I moved it to another area in my DB.

```
        public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public List<Claim> GetClaims()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Claim> loClaims = new List<Claim>();
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nAuthenticationType",          this._nAuthenticationType.ToString(),  this._nAuthenticationType.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nGridToolbarPosition",         this._nGridToolbarPosition.ToString(), this._nGridToolbarPosition.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nMode",                        this._nMode.ToString(),                 this._nMode.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nCultureId",                   this._nCultureId.ToString(),            this._nCultureId.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_bHideDashboard",               this._bHideDashboard.ToString(),        this._bHideDashboard.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nSalutation", this._nSalutation.ToString(), this._nSalutation.GetType().ToString()));
                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_nHOTPCounter", this._nHOTPCounter.ToString(), this._nHOTPCounter.GetType().ToString()));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._sFirstName))
                {
                    loClaims.Add(new Claim("_sFirstName",                   this._sFirstName.ToString(),            this._sFirstName.GetType().ToString()));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._sMiddleName))
                {
                    loClaims.Add(new Claim("_sMiddleName",                  this._sMiddleName.ToString(),           this._sMiddleName.GetType().ToString()));
                }

                loClaims.Add(new     Claim("_sLastName",                    this._sLastName.ToString(),             this._sLastName.GetType().ToString()));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._sMobile))
                {
                    loClaims.Add(new Claim("_sMobile",                      this._sMobile.ToString(),               this._sMobile.GetType().ToString()));
                }
```

Comment: Hi, @hkdave95, I am also getting the same issue. As your solution said to remove claim, can you please show me where actually it is and in which method I should look. I have checked the code but unable to find from where I can control or limit the claim to solve this ?

Comment: @Arun_TECH I made an edit on the post / hope that helps.